# Understanding difference between Pythons installed together with QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-3, windows-10

There is QGIS 3.20.3 installed on the Windows 10 in the `C:/Program Files/`.

[image: qgis_window]

What is a core difference between all Pythons delivered together with QGIS? What is the purpose of each one and what are the responsibilities?

For instance, I could find Python in:

- `C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.20.3/apps/Python39`
  [image: path_1]
- `C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.20.3/bin`
  [image: path_2]
- `C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.20.3/apps/qgis/python`
  [image: path_3]
- `C:/Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python`
  [image: path_4]

When I launched the Python Console and ran this code:

```
>>>import os
>>>import sys

>>>os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
```

I could get the following answer: `C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.20.3\\bin` this is a Python from `/bin`. Under this absolute path placed the executable binary for the Python interpreter.

However, when I typed this

```
>>>import os

>>>print(os.__file__)
```

I got this `C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS32~1.3\\apps\\Python39\\lib\\os.py` which is now a Python from `/apps`.

When I used this

```
>>>import qgis.core
   
>>>print(qgis.core.__file__)
```

I achieved his `C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.3/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\core\__init__.py`.

So, now I am wondering how to understand this Python labyrinth inside the QGIS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under Windows :

- *`OSGeo_root_directory`*`/apps/Python39`

  This is where the Python program is installed, in this case the 3.9 version.
- *`OSGeo_root_directory`*`/bin`

  This is just a directory with links, shortcuts for QGIS executables (with environment variable settings, etc.), in others, Python.
- *`OSGeo_root_directory`*`/apps/qgis/python`

  This is where QGIS PyQGIS and Python core modules are, they work with Python and extend QGIS functions with Python.
- *`%APPDATA%`*`/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python`

  This is where your custom Python expressions (extended QGIS expressions functionality) and installed plugins are stored.

In Python, you can have multiple directories (paths) where modules are installed and where Python search.

So when you import the module `os`, standard library, Python returns the path from the Python App, under the `Lib` directory where other standard libraries are installed.

[image: os_lib]

When you import `qgis.core`, you call the `qgis` module, that extents Python with QGIS Python API and it's located under the `apps/qgis/python` directory.

[image: qgis.core]